# Is there anyway I can refactor this to use array functions like filter, some etc

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've come up with this code which uses nested loops, trying to achieve the same result using array functions like `filter`, `some`, etc

https://jsfiddle.net/hw6of4je/

```js
let availableItems = [{
  "metric": "USD",
  "code": "USDONE",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "AUD",
  "code": "AUDTHREE",
  "quantity": "3"
}, {
  "metric": "AFN",
  "code": "AFNTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "ALL",
  "code": "ALLSIX",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "INR",
  "code": "INRTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}]


const masterSet = [{
  "uri": "marty-cruz.html",
  "name": "marty-cruz",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["USDONE", "USDTWO", "USDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "deanne-daniels.html",
  "name": "deanne-daniels",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AUDONE", "AUDTWO", "AUDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "sallie-pachecok.html",
  "name": "sallie-pachecok",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AFNTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "lillia-paul.html",
  "name": "lillia-paul",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["ALLONE", "ALLFOUR", "ALLSIX"]
}, {
  "uri": "ken-johnston.html",
  "name": "ken-johnston",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["INRTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "mary-stanton.html",
  "name": "mary-stanton",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["RODEWQ667"]
}, {
  "uri": "edwardo-brooks.html",
  "name": "edwardo-brooks",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["PADFER456"]
}]


let value = []
for (let item of availableItems) {
  for (let mainItem of masterSet) {
    if (mainItem.skuCodes.includes(item.code))
      value.push(mainItem)
  }
}

console.log(value)
```

If `code` from `availableItems` is present in one of the `skuCodes` of `masterSet`, I want that entry from `masterSet` in a new array.

Or the code I've come up with, is this the best way(readability and efficiency) this can be done.

Comment: What is the blueprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single line - but it's not very readable and not very efficient:

```
let value = masterSet.filter(mi => availableItems.some(ai => mi.skuCodes.includes(ai.code)));
```

Live demo:

```js
let availableItems = [{
  "metric": "USD",
  "code": "USDONE",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "AUD",
  "code": "AUDTHREE",
  "quantity": "3"
}, {
  "metric": "AFN",
  "code": "AFNTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "ALL",
  "code": "ALLSIX",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "INR",
  "code": "INRTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}]


const masterSet = [{
  "uri": "marty-cruz.html",
  "name": "marty-cruz",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["USDONE", "USDTWO", "USDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "deanne-daniels.html",
  "name": "deanne-daniels",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AUDONE", "AUDTWO", "AUDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "sallie-pachecok.html",
  "name": "sallie-pachecok",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AFNTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "lillia-paul.html",
  "name": "lillia-paul",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["ALLONE", "ALLFOUR", "ALLSIX"]
}, {
  "uri": "ken-johnston.html",
  "name": "ken-johnston",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["INRTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "mary-stanton.html",
  "name": "mary-stanton",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["RODEWQ667"]
}, {
  "uri": "edwardo-brooks.html",
  "name": "edwardo-brooks",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["PADFER456"]
}]


let value = masterSet.filter(mi => availableItems.some(ai => mi.skuCodes.includes(ai.code)));
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```js
let availableItems = [{
  "metric": "USD",
  "code": "USDONE",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "AUD",
  "code": "AUDTHREE",
  "quantity": "3"
}, {
  "metric": "AFN",
  "code": "AFNTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "ALL",
  "code": "ALLSIX",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "INR",
  "code": "INRTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}]


const masterSet = [{
  "uri": "marty-cruz.html",
  "name": "marty-cruz",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["USDONE", "USDTWO", "USDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "deanne-daniels.html",
  "name": "deanne-daniels",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AUDONE", "AUDTWO", "AUDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "sallie-pachecok.html",
  "name": "sallie-pachecok",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AFNTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "lillia-paul.html",
  "name": "lillia-paul",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["ALLONE", "ALLFOUR", "ALLSIX"]
}, {
  "uri": "ken-johnston.html",
  "name": "ken-johnston",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["INRTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "mary-stanton.html",
  "name": "mary-stanton",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["RODEWQ667"]
}, {
  "uri": "edwardo-brooks.html",
  "name": "edwardo-brooks",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["PADFER456"]
}]


let value = []
availableItems.forEach((item)=>{
  value.push(...(masterSet.filter((mainItem)=>(mainItem.skuCodes.includes(item.code)))))
})

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Array.prototype.filter to achieve that declaratively instead of writing imperative code using loops. I have done it in the below snippet.

**Let me explain:**
Array.prototype.filter takes in a callback function which can take upto 3 parameters -  the current **value**, the current **index** and the array itself, we just want the current value. We want to filter the **masterSet** where **availableItems** has at least one of the values from masterSet, for which we use the Array.prototype.some( ) function. The filter() function returns an array, so we can directly store this filtered array into the **value** variable.

```
     let value = masterSet.filter(item => {
       return availableItems.some(avItem => 
       item.skuCodes.includes(avItem.code));
     });
```

```js
let availableItems = [
  {
    metric: 'USD',
    code: 'USDONE',
    quantity: '1',
  },
  {
    metric: 'AUD',
    code: 'AUDTHREE',
    quantity: '3',
  },
  {
    metric: 'AFN',
    code: 'AFNTWO',
    quantity: '1',
  },
  {
    metric: 'ALL',
    code: 'ALLSIX',
    quantity: '1',
  },
  {
    metric: 'INR',
    code: 'INRTWO',
    quantity: '1',
  },
];

const masterSet = [
  {
    uri: 'marty-cruz.html',
    name: 'marty-cruz',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['USDONE', 'USDTWO', 'USDTHREE'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'deanne-daniels.html',
    name: 'deanne-daniels',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['AUDONE', 'AUDTWO', 'AUDTHREE'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'sallie-pachecok.html',
    name: 'sallie-pachecok',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['AFNTWO'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'lillia-paul.html',
    name: 'lillia-paul',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['ALLONE', 'ALLFOUR', 'ALLSIX'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'ken-johnston.html',
    name: 'ken-johnston',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['INRTWO'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'mary-stanton.html',
    name: 'mary-stanton',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['RODEWQ667'],
  },
  {
    uri: 'edwardo-brooks.html',
    name: 'edwardo-brooks',
    isVisible: false,
    skuCodes: ['PADFER456'],
  },
];

 let value = masterSet.filter(item => {
   return availableItems.some(avItem => 
   item.skuCodes.includes(avItem.code));
 });
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Sorry, this dosent seem to work for datasets where availableItems contains an object with code already surpassed by masterset index.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that was the requirement. I've modified my answer taking that into consideration :)  However, the answer you have currently chosen from the user jamierc is pretty much the exact same thing, so I recommend that you use his solution as he came up with it first. Goodluck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this one

```
const codes = availableItems.reduce((acc, {code}) => acc.add(code), new Set())
const value = masterSet.filter(({skuCodes}) => skuCodes.some((code) => codes.has(code)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more functional approach for sure. Whether it is better depends on your requirements. It may be less efficient but more readable and concise.

```
let test = masterSet.filter(x => availableItems.some(({ code }) => x.skuCodes.includes(code)))
```

```js
let availableItems = [{
  "metric": "USD",
  "code": "USDONE",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "AUD",
  "code": "AUDTHREE",
  "quantity": "3"
}, {
  "metric": "AFN",
  "code": "AFNTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "ALL",
  "code": "ALLSIX",
  "quantity": "1"
}, {
  "metric": "INR",
  "code": "INRTWO",
  "quantity": "1"
}]


const masterSet = [{
  "uri": "marty-cruz.html",
  "name": "marty-cruz",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["USDONE", "USDTWO", "USDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "deanne-daniels.html",
  "name": "deanne-daniels",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AUDONE", "AUDTWO", "AUDTHREE"]
}, {
  "uri": "sallie-pachecok.html",
  "name": "sallie-pachecok",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["AFNTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "lillia-paul.html",
  "name": "lillia-paul",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["ALLONE", "ALLFOUR", "ALLSIX"]
}, {
  "uri": "ken-johnston.html",
  "name": "ken-johnston",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["INRTWO"]
}, {
  "uri": "mary-stanton.html",
  "name": "mary-stanton",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["RODEWQ667"]
}, {
  "uri": "edwardo-brooks.html",
  "name": "edwardo-brooks",
  "isVisible": false,
  "skuCodes": ["PADFER456"]
}]


let test = masterSet.filter(x => availableItems.some(({ code }) => x.skuCodes.includes(code)))

console.log(test, test.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to first flatten the codes to an array, and filter according to it:

```
const codes = masterSet.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur.skuCodes), []);
const value =  availableItems.filter(it => codes.includes(it.code));
```

Another approach would be to use a sort of hash map:
(Not the cleanest solution, could be improved)

```
const codes = masterSet.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const local = cur.skuCodes.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return {
    ...acc,
    ...local
  }
}, {});
const value = availableItems.filter(it => codes[it.code])
```

Comment: It's much better to collect the codes into a Set, so you drastically reduce the lookup time.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, I was about to post another solution :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the OP is trying to filter the item from masterSet into a new array 'value', not the other way around.